How to create Azure logic app initialize variable after parse json action
i have a logic app in azure. i'm currently stuck in initialize expression variable after parse json. i want to catch "appId" parameter but all i get is null despite the fact that parse json giving an outout, so it seems that i I'm not expressing the right syntax.
this is my JSON output in parse JSON step
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "***********************",
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "accountEnabled": true,
      "alternativeNames": [],
      "appDisplayName": "testapp",
      "appDescription": null,
      "appId": "******************************",
      "applicationTemplateId": null,
      "appOwnerOrganizationId": "****************************",
      "appRoleAssignmentRequired": false,
      "createdDateTime": "2024-06-23T10:24:17Z",
      "description": null,
      "disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
      "displayName": "testapp",
      "homepage": null,
      "loginUrl": null,
      "logoutUrl": null,
      "notes": null,
      "notificationEmailAddresses": [],
      "preferredSingleSignOnMode": null,
      "preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint": null,
      "replyUrls": [],
      "servicePrincipalNames": [
        "********************************"
      ],
      "servicePrincipalType": "Application",
      "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
      "tags": [
        "HideApp",
        "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp"
      ],
      "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null,
      "samlSingleSignOnSettings": null,
      "addIns": [],
      "appRoles": [],
      "info": {
        "logoUrl": null,
        "marketingUrl": null,
        "privacyStatementUrl": null,
        "supportUrl": null,
        "termsOfServiceUrl": null
      },
      "keyCredentials": [],
      "oauth2PermissionScopes": [],
      "passwordCredentials": [],
      "resourceSpecificApplicationPermissions": [],
      "verifiedPublisher": {
        "displayName": null,
        "verifiedPublisherId": null,
        "addedDateTime": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "**********************8",
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "accountEnabled": true,
      "alternativeNames": [
        "isExplicit=False",
        "/subscriptions/******************************************/resourcegroups/Test-RG/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/test"
      ],
      "appDisplayName": null,
      "appDescription": null,
      "appId": "******************",
      "applicationTemplateId": null,
      "appOwnerOrganizationId": null,
      "appRoleAssignmentRequired": false,
      "createdDateTime": "2024-07-11T09:32:51Z",
      "description": null,
      "disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
      "displayName": "testeldad",
      "homepage": null,
      "loginUrl": null,
      "logoutUrl": null,
      "notes": null,
      "notificationEmailAddresses": [],
      "preferredSingleSignOnMode": null,
      "preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint": null,
      "replyUrls": [],
      "servicePrincipalNames": [
        "***********************",
        "https://identity.azure.net/*******************/**********************"
      ],
      "servicePrincipalType": "ManagedIdentity",
      "signInAudience": null,
      "tags": [],
      "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null,
      "info": null,
      "samlSingleSignOnSettings": null,
      "addIns": [],
      "appRoles": [],
      "keyCredentials": [
        {
          "customKeyIdentifier": "*****************",
          "displayName": "CN=**********************",
          "endDateTime": "2024-10-09T09:27:00Z",
          "key": null,
          "keyId": "*********************",
          "startDateTime": "2024-07-11T09:27:00Z",
          "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
          "usage": "Verify"
        }
      ],
      "oauth2PermissionScopes": [],
      "passwordCredentials": [],
      "resourceSpecificApplicationPermissions": [],
      "verifiedPublisher": {
        "displayName": null,
        "verifiedPublisherId": null,
        "addedDateTime": null
      }
    }
  ]
}

i tried using that syntax -->
first(outputs('Parse_JSON')?['body/value'])['appId'] and many many more :)
I'm using "first" coz there is a few appId instances in the output so i want to catch the first part. (don't know if it's the right way)
this is the compose result -


To get the first appId, instead of first(outputs('Parse_JSON')?['body/value'])['appId'] you should use this:
body('Parse_JSON')?['value']?[0]?['appId']

Testing:


Update:
Parsing the JSON before extracting field values is, strictly speaking, not required. For example, you are receiving a JSON content in the output of the HTTP action:

You can get the appId value from there as follows:
body('HTTP')?['value']?[0]?['appId']



Thanks @10p, well - the flow was to complete but the value returned empty :(

@monsal I added screenshot of a successful test to the answer

Thanks @10p, looks good. but from my end i don't get the same results - this is from my compose step - maybe the parse json schema in not accurate? (i've added a screen shot above)

@monsal, the JSON you are trying to parse - what action is it produced by? Can you share the full JSON and not a part of it?

yes, sorry. i will post it above.

the step before using the parse json is HTTP call for ms graph

@monsal, I've done another successful test using an HTTP call, receiving the JSON from your question, and getting the first appId value from there - added details to the end of my answer

That does the trick. Thanks a lot champ :)

You have to initialize variables at the start of your flow. You can Set Variable to update the value at any point during the flow. Logic apps should be showing you an error indicating that if you have added an init midway through.

Thanks Josh, actually I'm using Init at the start. what I want to achieve in that flow is rotating SPN secrets. so everything is working, except that when i want to pass the MS graph the SPN id for add a new secret and pass it back to key vault, the output is null, so thought using init after parse json again to see if i missed something.
